# Unity 2D Rigidbody.velocity and transform.position causes random 'ghost' frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am creating a 2D platform / adventure game that uses flip screen to manage changing rooms.

My character moves using `RigidBody.velocity`, this works as I need it to, when my character reaches one of the screen's left or right extremes I use transform.position to move (effectively teleporting) the character to the other side of the screen, I then change the room. This gives the effect of moving to the next room along.

My flip screen code works fine, the changing room effect works without a problem, in fact almost everything works just as I like it, except that I get 1 frame where the character appears at a random point in between where the character moved from and where he moved to.

For example, my room is 16 tiles across, if my character moves left and passes x position '0' (the very left of the screen) I make a transform.position to x position 16 (keeping the y position constant) and then change rooms. I have logged the movement and what happens is (pseudo code)..

```
x < 0 (the change room code is run)
translate.position to x=16 (the far right)
x = 16 (this is correct)
The room changes
x = some float somewhere between 0 and 16 (this is NOT correct)
x = 16 (back to the correct position again)
```

This is my player code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MKManager : MonoBehaviour {
public float maxSpeed = 0.10f;
bool isFacingRight = false;
Rigidbody2D myBody;
bool grounded = true;
public static int liftdirection = 0;

void Start (){
    myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void Update () {
    checkRoomBounds ();
}

void FixedUpdate(){
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
    if (grounded) {
        myBody.velocity = new Vector2 (h * maxSpeed, myBody.velocity.y);
        if (h < 0) { //Moving Left
            if (isFacingRight) {
                FlipAnimation ();
            }
        } else if (h > 0) { //Moving Right
            if (!isFacingRight) {
                FlipAnimation ();
            }
        }
    } 
}

void checkRoomBounds(){
    if (transform.position.x < 0) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (16.0f, transform.position.y, 0.0f);
        GameManager.instance.moveRoom (-1);
    } else if (transform.position.x > 16) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0.0f, transform.position.y, 0.0f);
        GameManager.instance.moveRoom (1);
    }
}

void FlipAnimation(){
    isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
}
```

I have tried calling `checkRoomBounds()` in update, fixed update and lateupdate, all give the same result. If I do not call the moveRoom() function the same happens but the room is not changed, but the `moveRoom()` code is...

```
public void moveRoom(int direction){
    if (room == 0) {
        room = (10*currentFloor) + 1;
    } else {

        room += direction;
        if (room == -1) {
            room = 68;
        } else if (room == 69) {
            room = 0;
        } else if (room % 10 == 9 || room % 10 == 0) {
            //room += (direction * 2);
            room = 0;
        }
    }
    boardScript.SetupScene (room);
}
```

I've run out of ideas and don't know where I'm going wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Does it still happens if you would change transform.position to myBody.position when you change room?

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it would apply in this case, but check your `Rigidbody2d`'s interpolation setting. In general it might do something like this, interpolating between previous position and next position. However I would think that only using `myBody.position` would have this problem, not `transform.position`.

Comment: I will check both of these and report back. Thanks.

Comment: It was, indeed, the interpolate. Many thanks for this, it's been bugging me for weeks! If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as the right one. Incidentally, it affects both myBody.position and transform.position.